# is there a bulkDelete equivalent of JDA?

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda, bulk-delete

In discord.js, there is a way to delete multiple messages in a channel (eventually making a clear command)

But I can't find the equivalent to Java Discord API. What I've tried is `message.getChannel().getLatestMessageId()`  in a for statement, but it gave me exceptions when doing so, and did not delete any message ofc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
channel.getIterableHistory()
  .takeAsync(amount)
  .thenAccept(channel::purgeMessages);
```

- [getIterableHistory](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/MessageChannel.html#getIterableHistory()) Gives access to retrieving any number of messages
- [purgeMessages](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/MessageChannel.html#purgeMessages(java.util.List)) does bulk delete (if possible)

Bulk delete is limited to up to 100 messages each and can only delete messages sent within the past 2 weeks. `purgeMessages` will split it into chunks of 100 and delete individual messages when they are too old. This can take a while since message delete is a very strictly limited endpoint.